# NSMutableStringの初期化方法はalloc init,new,string,のどれが最も良いか？

Tags: ios, objective-c

objective-cのNSMutableStringの初期化について質問です。

```
NSMutableString *ms1 = [NSMutableString string];
NSMutableString *ms2 = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
NSMutableString *ms3 = [NSMutableString new];
```

とございます。

そこで質問です。
・objective-cはどの初期化方法が理想的でしょうか。
・また、なぜその初期化方法が良いのでしょうか。

以上です、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5):

ARCが有効な環境なら、どれもおなじです。変わりや差異はありません。

メソッド`new`は、`alloc`+`init`の短縮書式、いわゆる「Syntax Sugar」です。
ARC有効でない環境では、`alloc`+`init`と`string`では違いがありました。`string`は、`alloc`+`init`+`autorelease`の短縮書式です。

Comment: プロジェクトやチームの場合は方針
個人の場合は、好みで良いということですね。
ありがとうございます。